# Search Engine (Algolia) Synonyms List Database for E-Commerce

Tags: search-engine, algolia, synonym

I'm trying to build a search engine for an e-commerce site selling a variety of items such as clothing, food, drinks, etc. I need to develop a synonym list, but have no idea where to start. Synonym.com seems like its synonyms are not concise enough for a search engine. Does anyone know where I can get a synonym database or where how to start building a synonyms list? I'm using algolia if that makes any difference. Thanks

Comment: I can answer for the Algolia part. What we advise is to build the list your self based on your products. Having a big list of synonyms will slow down the queries, and will reduce the relevancy.

Comment: right, but I need to have a starting place don't i for the synonyms?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like wordnet by princeton, moby dictionary, and open office are the best places to start right now.